# jQuery Waypoints sticky nav when scrolling up via a click is 1px off

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm close to tearing my hair out with Waypoints. First of all, I'm far from being experienced in javascript. I'm using Waypoints to 1) fix the nav to the top of the screen at a certain point (this works fine) and 2), highlight nav items when certain sections are reached. Everything works perfectly except when you click a nav item that requires the waypoint direction up, e.g. click "Exceptional Value" and then "Destinations." You'll notice that the waypoint seems to be a pixel off and "Exceptional Value" is still highlighted. If you scroll up a pixel, "Destinations" finally highlights. This is the only way to replicate this behavior... clicking nav items that scroll down works fine. Here is my JS: http://jsfiddle.net/TreUd/. Here is the site it's implemented on: http://ifb.thepinkrobot.com/. Thanks for any help... it's greatly appreciated.

```
        <!-- waypoints -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.nav-container').waypoint(function(direction) {
        $('nav#main').toggleClass('sticky', direction === 'down');  
      });
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sections = $("section");
        var navigation_links = $("nav a");

        sections.waypoint({
            handler: function(event, direction) {

                var active_section;
                active_section = $(this);
                if (direction === "down") active_section = active_section.prev();

                var active_link = $('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
                navigation_links.removeClass("selected");
                active_link.addClass("selected");

            },
            offset: 50
        })
    </script>
    <!-- end waypoints -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a strange one. There seems to be a 3px border on your header which might be causing the issue. However if you increase the offset of your waypoints from 50 to 53 seems to fix the problem.

```
var sections = $("section");
var navigation_links = $("nav a");

    sections.waypoint({
        handler: function (event, direction) {

            var active_section;
            active_section = $(this);
            if (direction === "down") active_section = active_section.prev();

            var active_link = $('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
            navigation_links.removeClass("selected");
            active_link.addClass("selected");

        },
        offset: 53
    })
```

Comment: I tried both changing offset to 53 and removing the 3px border (it was a 3px white top-border) and neither worked. What's weird is if the offset is 50, you see the issue when clicking links that move upwards on the page. If you increase the offset to 55, you see the issue when clicking links that move downwards on the page. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting development... in Firebug, try changing line-height on body from 1.5 to 20px... for some odd reason, it breaks the two sections I use column-count on (Destinations and Exceptional Value). However, doing this works for the other sections.

Comment: Figured this out. I removed event from the handler and changed the direction to up. Thanks for your help though, it was greatly appreciated.